# Google Header Image Sept 05 2011

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Wow, the Header animation commemorating Freddy Mercury is quite entertaining, and of course, no flash involved.  The style and script tags in the head contain about 24K of code, alot for one man to dissect.  Has anyone parsed it to understand, in general, the approach that Google took to this animation?

Also, why do they place the style and script 'inline'?  To reduce three http calls to one?  Or to increase cross-browser compatibility?

Is it best practice to merge my imported and linked script and style after development into the html file?

Comment: Am I the only one who saw a button with an arrow that has a circle around it when clicked?

Comment: it's actually an embedded youtube video.

Comment: Indeed @Tedil. Just look at the page using a web inspector and you'll notice an `object`.

Comment: FWIW its http://www.youtube.com/v/KX2BQM0D01M?autoplay=1&bgcolor=ffffff&enablejsapi=1&gestures=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&version=3&controls=0

Comment: Yes, it is this video : http://www.youtube.com/v/KX2BQM0D01M YouTube embedding and nothing more.

Comment: I am SO disappointed.  I could do it in javascript in 24K but using a hella bunch of images.  Any answers to the merging question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, don't merge your JavaScript scripts and style sheets inline; usually you'll want to use the same code and styles on different pages and if settings are correct, the script and style file(s) will be loaded once, every other page visit will use the cached one(s).

This has nothing to do with cross-browser compatibility. Google does this to reduce the number of HTTP calls; moreover, a script like this one will only be used at the front page. [In a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPBACTS-tyg), Matt Cutts from Google explains that the Google team did everything to squeeze every byte of their pages to reduce bandwidth.